# Animated Fractal Screen Saver

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, screensaver

Recently i got intrigued by the math of Fractals and now I am looking for a good quality (mandelbrot) fractal sceensaver. I thought that would be easy, but alas: looked around at the web, but could not find a decent one.

Hoping that one of the superusers can help me out.

Comment: Any particular OS?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: win7 64bit

Answer (score 1):

[Fractals Screensaver](http://download.cnet.com/Fractals-Screensaver/3000-2257_4-10776181.html) ? Works fine of Windows 7 64-bit.